# async function does not get called inside a component method when shallow testing with jest/enzyme

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

here's what the function looks like:

```
import { API } from './location'

class Dummy {
    getDummy = async () => {
        await API.dummy()
    }
}
```

and the test case:

```
it('calls getDummy as expected', async () => {
    await wrapper.instance().getDummy()
})
```

when the test is run with `jest --coverage`, it shows that the line `await API.dummy()` is not covered

is this a normal behavior? how do you suggest i test this case of the code?

Comment: what part of the code calls `getDummy`?

Comment: the test does. my bad, edited.